# WPA_GUI can't load wpa_supplicant, sudo ifup wlan0 -> Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0

Tags: wifi

New to raspberry pi, no idea how to troubleshoot this problem. Could it be a hardware problem?

http://pastebin.com/LFpcBZVB

/etc/network/interfaces
    auto lo

```
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wla0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

ifconfig & iwconfig

```
> ifconfig:

wnla0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:13:ef:10:13:94
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)</code>

> iwconfig

wlan0 associated Nickname:"< WIFI@REALTEK >"
Mode:Auto Frequency=2.412 GHz Access Point: Not-Associated
Sensitivity:0/0
Retry: off RTS thr:off Fragment thr: off
Power management: off
link quality:0 signal level:0 noise level:0
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:0 missed beacon:0
```

Comment: What do the commands `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` display?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn ifconfig: wnal0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:13:ef:10:13:94
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

Comment: @HeatfanJohn iwconfig: wlan0 associated Nickname:"< WIFI@REALTEK >"
Mode:Auto Frequency=2.412 GHz Access Point: Not-Associated
Sensitivity:0/0
Retry: off RTS thr:off Fragment thr: off
Power management: off
link quality:0 signal level:0 noise level:0
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:0 missed beacon:0

Comment: I added your information to your question.  Did `ifconfig` really display `wnal0` or is that just a typo and should be `wlan0`?  Also, please add the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to the question.

Comment: Also what wireless card is it? Output from lsusb and dmesg may be helpful. (Consider using http://pastebin.net/)

Comment: @Fred its some sort of realtek card that came with the bundle i got. http://pastebin.com/LFpcBZVB

Comment: @HeatfanJohn whoops, that was meant to be wlan0. http://pastebin.com/LFpcBZVB has all of the print outs

Comment: Please update or post a new pastebin, the pastebin you're using still shows typos where wlan0 should be.  Also please post your supplicant file (masking out any passwords or confidential information).

Comment: lsmod and uname -a might also be useful. I suspect there may be a driver problem.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a typo in your `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
iface wla0 inet manual
```

`wla0` should be `wlan0`

Comment: fixed, but wifi still isn't working.
wpa_supplicant.conf contains: 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssidd="NETWORK_NAME"
psk=""
proto = WPA
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise = TKIP
auth_alg = OPEN
}

Answer (score 0):

Got issue with same symptoms, **no connections**, scan with `iwlist` ok with all the networks access points. `ifconfig` list the card as wlan0.

Was suspecting the power source to be too weak.

Using a **cheap tp-link wifi card**, [none of the default raspberry tutorial was working](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/), nor most of online tutorials.

[This method is working for me.](https://askubuntu.com/a/279333/639641). Using the interactive method of **wpa_passphrase**.

```
wpa_passphrase YOURWIFINAME > wpa.conf
RETURN
yourwifipassword
RETURN
sudo dhcpcd wlan0 
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c ~/wpa.conf
```

Network immediately available after that.

---

To execute those commands automatically at system startup.

Edit `/etc/rc.local`

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Sample content. The full path must be specified for your config file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e   
sudo dhcpcd wlan0
sudo wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /home/pi/wpa.conf
exit 0
```

Give execution right to `/etc/rc.local`

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

This shows another way to force some particular setup on startup for headless it's beautiful.

Comment: I removed the picture at the end of your post because frankly I couldn't see what purpose it served.